# Color Specific Hue/Saturation from Photoshop to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-image, gpuimage, cifilter

I'm trying to use GPUImage and CIFilter to map this filter. Please note, I need help mapping the color (Reds) specific (note: NOT Master, just Reds) photoshop element to iOS.

Does anyone know how to manipulate a CIFilter or GPUImage class to get the photoshop effect below in iOS?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to find the RGB values of the color?  It appears to be 2d7878 in HTML notation (roughly R:0.176 G:0.471 B:0.471 for most iOS purposes)

Comment: This layer changes the reds in the photo, adjusting the hue, saturation, and lightness just for the reds.

Comment: @Eric Have you managed to make this effect? Is there a way to use .ahu file exported from photoshop in GPUImage class?

Answer (score 2):

You could use GPUImage with the lookup filter:

> GPUImageLookupFilter: Uses an RGB color lookup image to remap the
>   colors in an image. First, use your favourite photo editing
>   application to apply a filter to lookup.png from
>   GPUImage/framework/Resources. For this to work properly each pixel
>   color must not depend on other pixels (e.g. blur will not work). If
>   you need a more complex filter you can create as many lookup tables as
>   required. Once ready, use your new lookup.png file as a second input
>   for GPUImageLookupFilter.

So apply all color filters in the lookup.png file from GPUImage in Photoshop, save it, then apply the filter:

```
- (UIImage *)applyMyFilter:(UIImage*)inputImage {
    //apply custom filter
    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];

    GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-lookup.png"]];
    GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
    [stillImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];
    [lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];

    [stillImageSource processImage];
    [lookupImageSource processImage];
    UIImage *adjustedImage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

    return adjustedImage;
}
```