# UIImage - highlight single color only

Tags: uiimage, core-image, gpuimage

I need to convert an image to greyscale except for a single color. For example, if there is some red in the image (like a red bus), this will remain in color, but the rest of the image will remain in black & white.

I think I should be able to do a rudimentary job of this by going over each pixel individually, such as here: http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage . I am assuming I would just leave certain pixels alone if their red component was above a certain amount, and green/blue was below a certain amount. Otherwise, set the pixel to grayscale. Is this a good approach?

I'm more interested in whether or not it is possible to do to the live camera input, such as with a `Core Image` filter, or using `GPUImage`, but I haven't been able to find any suitable filters. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

This seems to be possible using `GPUImage` with a `GPUImageLookupFilter`, as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19340583/334982

I've created a lookup.png file in Photoshop, by dropping the Saturation for all colours except red to 0. This works ok, but it doesn't seem to grey out all colours. For example, my skin still looks fairly skin coloured, and my brown table is still fairly brown.